# Truffle- how to deploy ERC20 on local, but not public network, without the error "X is an abstract contract or an interface and cannot be deployed"?

Tags: erc-20, truffle-migration

So, I have a contract, let's call it contract A, that needs to make call to the Dai contract (referred to as Cash). This contract already exists on Kovan, so in 2deploy_contracts.js I simply set its address and pass it to my contract as a constructor variable:

```
var contractA = artifacts.require("./contractA.sol");
var cashAddress = 0x..;

module.exports = function(deployer, network) {
 if(network === "kovan") {
 deployer.deploy(contractA, cashAddress);
 }
}
```

contractA.sol, in addition to the contractA contract, has a Cash interface which describes all the functions of this already existing contract:

```
interface Cash 
{
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address _ownesr) external view returns (uint256);
    function faucet(uint256 _amount) external;
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool);
}
```

And within the contractA constructor we have:

```
Cash cash = Cash(cashAddress);
```

The cash variable is then interacted with at various times, for example:

```
cash.transfer(_to,_amount);)
```

All well and good. The problem is that for local ganache testing, there is not an already deployed Cash contract, so I need to deploy it myself. I have created Cash.sol: (Im aware its shitty and not ERC20, Im only using it for local testing):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Cash 
{

mapping (address => uint256) balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256 ) ) allowances;

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool)
{
    allowances[_spender][msg.sender] = _amount;
    return true;
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256)
{
    return balances[_owner];
}

function faucet(uint256 _amount) external
{
    balances[msg.sender] = _amount;
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool)
{   
    require (balances[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] - _amount;
    balances[_to] = balances[_to] + _amount;
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool)
{
    require (allowances[msg.sender][_from] >= _amount, "Insufficient approval");
    require (balances[_from] >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
    balances[_from] = balances[_from] - _amount;
    balances[_to] = balances[_to] + _amount;
    return true;
}

}
```

And in my 2deploy_contracts.js I need to pass the address of the newly created contract to contractA as follows:

```
var Cash = artifacts.require("./Cash.sol");
var contractA = artifacts.require("./contractA.sol");
var cashAddress = 0x..;

module.exports = function(deployer, network) {
 if(network === "development") {
 deployer.deploy(Cash).then((deployedCash) => {
      return deployer.deploy(ContractA, deployedCash.address)
 }
}
```

But when I try and do development deploy, I get the "Cash is an abstract contract or an interface and cannot be deployed" error.

I'm aware that Cash is an abstract contract (because its just an interface) within contractA.sol. But in 2deploy_contracts.js the object 'Cash' points to Cash.sol, NOT to the interface within contractA.sol. So why is truffle making a fuss?

I thought maybe the problem was that there are two different contracts with the same name- Cash. So for the 'local' version I changed the contract name to localCash (both the file name, and the name of the contract). Then it deploys fine, but since contractA has an interface for Cash and not localCash it can't find the contract at the given address. So it would seem that the name of the interface MUST match the name of the full deployed contract.

Wat do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
contract Cash
```

To this:

```
import './Cash.sol';
contract CashMockup is Cash
```

And this

```
var Cash = artifacts.require("./Cash.sol");
```

To this:

```
var Cash = artifacts.require("CashMockup");
```

---

For future reference, keep in mind that while the Solidity's `import` statement imports one or more contracts by file-name, the Truffle's `artifacts.require` statement imports a single contract by contract-name.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your rapid response!! First of all, do you mean `var Cash = artifacts.require("./CashMockup");` instead of `var Cash = artifacts.require("CashMockup");` (for the sake of consistency :) )? Anyway I have tried this and the error I get is "Cash not found on network ID: 1579607485454"

Comment: Also, I'm a bit confused as to what should go in the rest of the CashMockup.sol file after `contract CashMockup is Cash`- the same as what is in Cash.sol? Nothing? Something in between?

Comment: @AndrewStanger: You're welcome. With regards to your first question - please read the paragraph at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @AndrewStanger: With regards to your second question - it's hard to answer it when you haven't specified any of your file names, leaving the reader to guess which piece of code is located where. Personally, I have guessed that `interface Cash` is located inside file `Cash.sol`. Did I guess wrong? In any case, I wrote "replace `contract Cash` with `contract CashMockup is Cash`", so you obviously need to add under `contract CashMockup is Cash` everything that you originally had under `contract Cash`.

Comment: @goodvibrations Re first question- apologies, my question made no sense, I had not acknowledged the lack of .sol on the end, I thought you had just omitted the "./" accidentally. However, still a bit confused- the line `var Cash = artifacts.require("CashMockup")` - where does truffle look for the contract named CashMockup if I'm not specifying a filename?

Comment: @goodvibrations Re. second question- further apologies, I thought I had mentioned where the Cash interface is- it is not in `Cash.sol`, it is in `contractA.sol` (I think it has to be here? otherwise contractA would not be able to interact with the Cash contract). So anyway, I have kept `Cash.sol` for what it was originally, created a `CashMockup.sol` which is the same as `Cash.sol` except it imports `Cash.sol` and has `contract CashMockup is Cash` instead of just `contract Cash` as instructed. And I still get `"Cash not found on network ID: 1579607485454"`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AndrewStanger: With regards to your first question - Truffle goes to the JSON files created by `truffle compile`, where it finds the `CashMockup` contract's artifacts (abi and bytecode). BTW, you might understand that as a result of this, a Truffle project does not allow you to have two contracts of the same name (even if placed in two different files).

Comment: @AndrewStanger: With regards to "I think it has to be here? otherwise contractA would not be able to interact with the Cash contract" - No, you can place the Cash interface in a different file and have the file where contractA is implemented importing that other file.

Comment: @AndrewStanger: With regards to your second question - when exactly do you get this error? i.e., what set of actions do you perform which ends up with this error being issued?

Comment: @goodvibrations I continue to be extremely grateful for your help. If you are up for it, could we move to telegram? My ID is mcplums. Meanwhile, I understand your first two responses 100%, thanks.

Comment: @goodvibrations Re. where I get that error, you are quite right, I am being entirely confusing again. With your changes eveything deploys fine. The error is actually in the front end, in the chrome console  to be specific, when I load a page that attempts to call from the Cash contract. This may be getting off topic, but I notice that my `drizzleOptions.js` has the line `import Cash from "./contracts/Cash.json";` should it be CashMockup.json instead?

Comment: @AndrewStanger: I would imagine so, but I have not been experiencing with Truffle and/or Web3 running on front-end side, so I'm not sure I can help you with that part.

Comment: @goodvibrations ok, understood. thanks for everything. So yes, it does work if I import CashMockup.json instead. But then, if I'm deploying to Kovan, it of course won't work anymore, because the already deployed contract is Cash, not CashMockup. So I would need to change the function call the front end is doing depending  on where the contract is deployed, an extremely ungraceful solution. In conclusion, what I'm trying to do, is not really possible in any straightforward sense :)

Comment: @AndrewStanger: I disagree your conclusion. I believe that if things are implemented correctly, then all you need to do is deploying two contracts (mockup and operational), and alternate between their addresses as needed. I lack a certain amount of knowledge about your system connectivity (i.e., your software modules and the relations between them), so I cannot give you an off-the-shelf solution to your specific problem. But you might wanna do an overview of your code in order to find one.

Comment: @goodvibrations so I think there is something I'm not understanding then. My understanding, from what you have said, is that the local contract MUST have a different name to the interface within my main contract, or truffle will confuse the two. Likewise, the front end MUST point to a contract of different name depending on whether I'm using the mockup or the real version. There is therefore no solution that does not involve messing around in the front end (except for just changing addresses, of course)

Comment: @goodvibrations regardless, an alternative solution occurs- I can simply deploy the local contract using a seperate truffle instance, and manually pass its address to my main truffle project the same way I pass it the address of the kovan contract :)

Comment: @AndrewStanger: Yes. You don't necessarily need to have both contracts on the same Truffle project.

Comment: @goodvibrations turns out I was wrong anyway in what I was saying. There is NO need to change the contract name that the front end points to- simply change the address within Cash.json. What I had not acknowledged was that (please correct me if I'm wrong!) the contract name is not actually relevant when making contract calls. All you need is the address and the function selector hash. So the fact that I have deployed 'CashMockup' instead of 'Cash' does not stop my front end interacting with 'Cash' if the correct address is in Cash.json.

Comment: @goodvibrations and further, I do not need to do anything fancy to change addresses since the jsons allow you to specify a different address for different networks. So just a one time thing. Awesome!! You have helped alot :)